# Rx subscribeOn mainThread not working with PublishSubject Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have a problem with this block of code

```
    val obs = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

    obs
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe{ value -> 
              Log.i("TEST", "$value")
        }

    (1..4).forEach { obs.onNext(it) }
```

When I use **subscribeOn** **mainThread** and call **onNext**() nothing happens,nothing printed out.. It works well with **subscribeOn** **Schedulers.io()** or **Schedulers.computation()**

I dont know if its because im already in **main thread** and call **subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())** but when i try calling these block of code in some random worker thread then it works well

Comment: Yes, the reason it doesn't work because you are already on the main thread and no actual subscription would happen until you give it up. Also in general, `subscribeOn` has no practical use for `Subject`s.